# Can't brew install MariaDB 5.5 on Mac OS

Tags: mariadb, homebrew

does anyone know how I could install MariaDB 5.5 server with Homebrew on Mac OS? I've tried running brew install mariadb@5.5 but it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also Try Building it from source!

you can use Homebrew to build MariaDB from source.Its helpful if you want to use a different version of the server or enable some different capabilities that are not included in the bottle package or if you are having issues with the bottle package.

To build MariaDB Server with these engines, you must first install boost and judy.

And please can you be specific about the errors you encountered.
You might want to check this site: